# How to write alternative constraint with interval variable in or-tools?

Tags: or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

How to write alternative constraint with interval variable in or-tools? I thought something like this would work but the method AddAlternative doesn´t exist. Another question is how to know if interval variable is active

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

# Crear el modelo
model = cp_model.CpModel()

# Crear la variable de intervalo
interval = model.NewIntervalVar(start, end, duration, 'interval')

# Crear los intervalos alternativos
alt_interval1 = model.NewIntervalVar(start1, end1, duration1, 'alt_interval1')
alt_interval2 = model.NewIntervalVar(start2, end2, duration2, 'alt_interval2')

# Agregar los intervalos alternativos a la variable de intervalo
model.AddAlternative(interval, [alt_interval1, alt_interval2])

# Resolver el modelo
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)
```

My code is:

```
# VARIABLES#
x = [
    model.NewIntervalVar(
        start=model.NewIntVar(es, lf, f"start_{row.id_pozo}"),
        size=model.NewIntVar(es, lf, f"size_{row.id_pozo}"),
        end=model.NewIntVar(es, lf, f"end_{row.id_pozo}"),
        name="pozo_intv_{}".format(row.id_pozo),
    )
    for row in pozos.itertuples()
]

y = [
    model.NewOptionalIntervalVar(
        start=model.NewIntVar(row.dia_inicio, row.dia_fin, f"start_{idx}"),
        size=row.tiempo_total,
        end=model.NewIntVar(row.dia_inicio, row.dia_fin, f"end_{idx}"),
        is_present=True,
        name="pte_intv_{}".format(idx),
    )
    for idx, row in pozo_time_equipment.iterrows()
]
```

Comment: I hope you are aware that Chat GPT does not give you facts or true information, it makes everything up as it goes along. This really becomes apparent in code where you can test if it is right or wrong. Use of Chat GPT is also forbidden on StackOverflow, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1

Comment: calm good man, my code is legitimate and my question is legitimate

Comment: The OP edited his post to replace "Chat GPT tells me" with "I thought". The code does look legit, although I haven't actually tested it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a flexible job shop problem. In the [OR tools source](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/flexible_job_shop_sat.py) there is a working example. The basics are, firstly creating the main interval for each task:

```
    # Create main interval for the task.
    suffix_name = '_j%i_t%i' % (job_id, task_id)
    start = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'start' + suffix_name)
    duration = model.NewIntVar(min_duration, max_duration,
                               'duration' + suffix_name)
    end = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'end' + suffix_name)
    interval = model.NewIntervalVar(start, duration, end,
                                    'interval' + suffix_name)
```

Then for each alternative, create an additional interval:

```
            alt_suffix = '_j%i_t%i_a%i' % (job_id, task_id, alt_id)
            l_presence = model.NewBoolVar('presence' + alt_suffix)
            l_start = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'start' + alt_suffix)
            l_duration = task[alt_id][0]
            l_end = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'end' + alt_suffix)
            l_interval = model.NewOptionalIntervalVar(
                l_start, l_duration, l_end, l_presence,
                'interval' + alt_suffix)
            l_presences.append(l_presence)
```

The alternative is linked to the main interval, only if the alternative is selected:

```
            # Link the primary/global variables with the local ones.
            model.Add(start == l_start).OnlyEnforceIf(l_presence)
            model.Add(duration == l_duration).OnlyEnforceIf(l_presence)
            model.Add(end == l_end).OnlyEnforceIf(l_presence)
```

Then finally, add a constraint to ensure that only one of the alternatives is selected:

```
        # Select exactly one presence variable.
        model.AddExactlyOne(l_presences)
```